# Google Analytics and deciphering where the stats came from on a single domain but multiple use application

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Got a bit of a quandary that I am hoping someone might be able to help with. I am building a touch screen application in HTML / JavaScript to run on upward of 4 pods (Touchscreens). It will be running from a single domain ... "*www.touchscreen.com*" (Example URL) but each pod has a unique ID that is being passed around to grab data, send data etc. so that I know what pod is being used.

I have programmed in the ability for every touch / button press to be captured by a single UA code within Google Analytics (*analytics.js*), with a combination of normal “pageview” sends and some event tracking. Through testing this works really well. However, in the real world we need the ability to decipher which pod the stats came from; podID 1 through to 4 in this example.

I have tried various thing such as:

```
ga('set', 'dataSource', 'podID1');
```

OR changing the client ID or tracker name per pod but it doesn't seem to do what we want it to do. I guess we could setup multiple UA codes, one for each pod, but would rather have everything in the same pot … but be able to split them up if needs be for buttons presses per pod etc.

How would I go about doing this? What is the correct way for something like this to post stats from a single domain but know which version of and application the stats belonged to.

Hope that makes sense and any help on the above would be appreciated.

Many thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) to track the pod number. Just set it on the tracker at create time, and all subsequent hits will have this dimensions, so you can access it in your reporting.

You can set a custom dimension as follows (replace 'XX' with the dimension ID in the Google Analytics admin):

```
// Setting a custom dimension at create time.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {dimensionXX: podNumber});

// Alternatively you can update the tracker with the
// custom dimension at any time after creating the tracker.
ga('set', 'dimensionsXX', podNumber);
```

More information about using custom dimensions with analytics.js can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Where would you find these in the actual analytics? Been clickgin stats for 2 days with the custom dimension on, using different podID's but cant find where to actually view these?

Comment: Since custom dimensions aren't the same for all users, they're not in any standard report, but you can make a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) with your custom dimensions in them. You could also use the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) as it supports custom dimensions as well.